# Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Devices' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF – ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Сразу внесу ясность: добавление строки `context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT Devices ON");` ровно перед строкой, в которой возникает описанное в названии исключение НЕ ДАЁТ НИКАКОГО ЭФФЕКТА. Ошибка остаётся в том же виде.

Теперь сам вопрос: при попытке записать объект класса в базу данных (вместе с ID-полем) вылетает исключение, как указано в названии вопроса. Есть ли какой-то более элегантный и надёжный способ установить `IDENTITY_INSERT` для таблицы в `ON`, чем отправка голого SQL-запроса?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Да, C#. EF Core.

Answer (score 1):

Элегантный и надежный способ - не писать в IDENTITY поле. А чтобы сработало  с `SET IDENTITY_INSERT`, нужно все выполнять одной командой:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Devices ON;

INSERT Devices (Id, Value)
SELECT @Id, @Value;

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Devices OFF;
```

Как вариант, чтобы не возиться с этим в C# коде, можно создать хранимую процедуру для вставки в `Devices` и просто вызывать ее с параметрами @Id, @Value и тп.

Comment: Но есть же возможность делать INSERT без сырых SQL-запросов, почему тогда нет возможности установить это свойство похожим способом? Неужели обязательно писать эти голые строки, в которых по пол часа приходится потом выискивать любую описку?

Comment: Если приходится устанавливать это свойство, значит какая-то авария произошла, для обычной работы в переключении туда-сюда свойства `IDENTITY_INSERT` не должно быть необходимости. Здесь посмотрите [Entity Framework Tutorial](https://entityframework.net/identity-insert).